# Image caption - I dont want it to fade away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I am making my index page, which is blocks of images with caption. The actual image is colored, but I set them so they can be loaded black/white. And when they hover over, they turn colored. However, when I hover over the image, it turns colored, but the "figurecaption" fades away, which has the link. And I dont want that. So can anyone help me out :/

(Tried to jfiddle, but the code won't work 100%, so ill copy/paste, and post link to my website)
http://leaguerage.net/beta

Javascript:

```
// On window load. This waits until images have loaded which is essential
$(window).load(function(){

    // Fade in images so there isn't a color "pop" document load and then on window load
    $("#sliding-container figure img").fadeIn(500);

    // clone image
    $('#sliding-container figure img').each(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        el.css({"position":"absolute"}).wrap("<div class='img_wrapper' style='display: inline-block'>").clone().addClass('img_grayscale').css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"998","opacity":"0"}).insertBefore(el).queue(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            el.parent().css({"width":this.width,"height":this.height});
            el.dequeue();
        });
        this.src = grayscale(this.src);
    });

    // Fade image 
    $('#sliding-container figure img').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
    })
    $('.img_grayscale').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
    });     
});

// Grayscale w canvas method
function grayscale(src){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = src;
    canvas.width = imgObj.width;
    canvas.height = imgObj.height; 
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0); 
    var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
        for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
            var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
            var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
            imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sliding-container">
    <figure>

        <img id="imgblocks" src="blocks/newsite.png" alt="">
        <figcaption><a href="#">Welcome to the new LeagueRage.net!</a></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img id="imgblocks" src="blocks/forums.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Visit our forums! Join the community!</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a z-index to caption.

```
 figcaption {
 z-index:10000;
 }
```